# Asp.net and Google developer console -- redirect URI mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I have spent two days now to set the redirect uri in Google developer and in my Visual Studio project. I know there are a lot of similar questions about this topic but I couldn´t solve the problem until now.

Client id and client secret is configured. My path is:  localhost:53491

Redirect uri in Visual studio: http://localhost:53491/Account/GoogleAuthorization

Account/GoogleAuthorization is the methode in my controller which should handle the token from the google server!

What I have to set now on 'Goolge developers console' as the 'Authorized redirect URI' I tried thousands of variations but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `Account/GoogleAuthorization` in your redirect uri. Base on the examples given in [Choosing a redirect URI](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi):

> The redirect URI specified in the request determines how the authorization code is returned to your application.

Here is the list of redirect URI:

- `http://localhost[:port]`
- `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`
- `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto`

> **Note**: In some cases, although it is possible to listen, other software
>   (such as a Windows firewall) prevents delivery of the message without
>   significant client configuration.